# How to get mp3 decoding to work with gstreamer 0.10 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, plugins, gstreamer

After upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, my most favourite application suddenly stopped playing music with the error message:

```
** Message: don't know how to handle audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, mpegaudioversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2, parsed=(boolean)true
 pid:17764: (media plugin) processGSTEvents:273: GST error: You do not have a decoder installed to handle this file. You might need to install the necessary plugins.
 pid:17764: (media plugin) processGSTEvents:273: GST error: Internal data flow error.
```

Investigation shows that this codec was in gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly, but that doesn't exist anymore in 16.04!? There is a gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, but this application isn't using gstreamer1.0 and doesn't look for it.

How can I get my plugins back? I will need the 'bad' plugins too.

Note that I already tried installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, but that didn't help.

Comment: I would prefer to comment with this question, but am not permitted. While trying to use the Carlo Wood solution, I get an error at this command: sudo apt-get build-dep gst-plugins-ugly1.0 E: Unable to find a source package for gst-plugins-ugly1.0 I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: @KenH Do you have a deb-src line in your /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Answer (score 1):

First I tried to port the application to gstreamer1.0, but that is IMPOSSIBLE...

In the end I got my music working again with the following:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gst-plugins-ugly0.10/gst-plugins-ugly0.10_0.10.19-2ubuntu5.dsc
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gst-plugins-ugly0.10/gst-plugins-ugly0.10_0.10.19-2ubuntu5.debian.tar.gz
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gst-plugins-ugly0.10/gst-plugins-ugly0.10_0.10.19.orig.tar.bz2
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts debhelper docbook-to-man
sudo apt-get build-dep gst-plugins-ugly1.0
dpkg-source -x gst-plugins-ugly0.10_0.10.19-2ubuntu5.dsc
cd gst-plugins-ugly0.10-0.10.19
vi debian/rules
```

comment out:

```
#ifeq (,$(findstring $(DEB_HOST_ARCH),m68k arm))
#DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS += --enable-gtk-doc
#endif
```

because making the docs didn't work.

```
vi debian/control
```

Remove the whole gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-doc Package: .. Description, otherwise if now fails to create the .deb.

```
DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH="$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)" debian/rules -j 8 build-arch
fakeroot debian/rules binary
sudo dpkg -i ../gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly_0.10.19-2ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Enjoy